# this.props.match.params passed into child component after authorisation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, authentication, react-router-dom

I have recently started building a big project on React using also a Firebase with authentication and I cannot quite understand the relation between the react-router-dom links and React components.

I am struggling with getting the

```
this.props.match.params // which is going to be 2018 / 2019 / 2020... etc
```

in the component, which renders as a dynamic route (like unique post component).

I have tried to use only a simple class component and this works but the problem is, without the authentication everyone can access this admin route and everyone would be allowed to edit and delete data there. I want it to be accessed only by authenticated users. (Admins)

So this is how my piece of code looks like:

Main component: (where the link is)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

class SeasonBox extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Link className='seasonbox' to={`/adminseason/${this.props.season}`}>
                <p className='seasonbox__season'>{this.props.season}/{this.props.season+1}</p>
            </Link>
        )
    }
}

export default SeasonBox;
```

And the component that renders after the link is clicked:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { compose } from 'recompose'
import { withAuthorisation } from '../Session'
import { withFirebase } from '../Firebase'


const AdminMatchesBox = ({authUser}) => (
    <div>{authUser ? <AdminMatchesBoxAuth /> : <AdminMatchesBoxNonAuth />} </div>
)

class AdminMatchesBoxAuth extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                Hey I am the season {this.props.match.params}!

                <Link to={'/adminmatches'}>Wróć</Link>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const AdminMatchesBoxNonAuth = () => (
    <div>
        <h1>You do not have permission to visit this page.</h1>
    </div>
)

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    authUser: state.sessionState.authUser
});

const condition = authUser => !!authUser


export default compose(withAuthorisation(condition), connect(mapStateToProps),withFirebase)(AdminMatchesBox);
```

So if I don't use authorisation, and I use only a single class component I can get this.props.match.params -> which is the id of the website and I need it to access data from the database.

However, I want it to not be visible by not logged users and I had to process it through the authorisation process.

I am receiving an error

```
Cannot read property 'params' of undefined.
```

I have no clue how to pass match.params into the AdminMatchesBoxAuth component.

Could anyone advice?

Comment: have you tried wrapping the component  with `withRouter` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By wrapping withRouter you able to access params

Try this

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router";
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
    import { connect } from 'react-redux'
    import { compose } from 'recompose'
    import { withAuthorisation } from '../Session'
    import { withFirebase } from '../Firebase'


    const AdminMatchesBox = ({authUser}) => (
        <div>{authUser ? <AdminMatchesBoxAuth /> : <AdminMatchesBoxNonAuth />} </div>
    )

    class AdminMatchesBoxAuth extends Component {
        constructor (props){
          super(props)
         }
        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    Hey I am the season {this.props.match.params}!

                    <Link to={'/adminmatches'}>Wróć</Link>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

    const AdminMatchesBoxNonAuth = () => (
        <div>
            <h1>You do not have permission to visit this page.</h1>
        </div>
    )

    const mapStateToProps = state => ({
        authUser: state.sessionState.authUser
    });

    const condition = authUser => !!authUser


    export default compose(withRouter, withAuthorisation(condition), connect(mapStateToProps),withFirebase)(AdminMatchesBox)
```

Comment: Thank you, there is a little bit of the progress but I am still receiving an error:

I can access `this.props.match` but not `this.props.match.params` :( It returns an error that 'params' is undefined

Comment: How you wrote route for it ?

Comment: the route is `export const ADMINSEASON = '/adminseason/:id';`

Comment: and in App.js I've got `<Route path={ROUTES.ADMINSEASON} component={AdminMatchesBox} />`

Comment: Console this.props and see

Comment: nothing there, that's the main struggle. Only the basic prototypes

Comment: I have edited the answer can you please try that. I have added constructor in class

Comment: still 'params' undefined :(

Comment: it works perfectly if I have only one class, if I have more components like in this case it goes crazy, but I have no idea how to authorise it in a different way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197297/discussion-between-jits-and-jhrwekuh).